# How to make a link to lead to word+word instead of http//

Tags: html, hyperlink

If a user type **word and another word** , most browsers will lead the user to a Google search for these words. I want to make a link, which when clicked leads to opening a background tab, whose address is just plain words with no http included. 
I have a script for the background link, so I just need a solution for the other part. I am thinking about following options:

1. the link redirect to address, that make the magic via sending raw header instructions
2. the link redirect to a php file, which set a new location
3. I find a way to read the URL, before it is send and striping it

There are wild guesses, as unfortunately my knowledge is not enough to find a solution on my own. I will be happy if somebody help me, otherwise I will have to go with uglier solution for the functionality I want to build.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. `%20` is what is used in URLs because spaces aren't allowed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the space issue as well. I try to solve the big problem first, before going further, but if I manage to solve it, I will have to think for the space as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible. For a workaround look at the bottom.

The feature in the browser you are talking about, is depended on the vendor. There is no `standard` for it, means there is no independed `API` for it.

Even is a link (also known as `Uniform Resource Locator`), by definition not able to do this. From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator):

> A uniform resource locator (abbreviated URL; also known as a web
>   address, particularly when used with HTTP) is a specific character
>   string that constitutes a reference to a resource

Why not calling http://google.com/search?q=firstword+secondword?

You can simple `urlencode` your Words and append it to `http://google.com/search?q=`

Comment: Thanks Christian! Your suggestion was similar to the uglier solution, that I had in mind. Calling http://google.com/search?q=firstword+secondword will work just fine, but I really wanted to make the initial idea work, which obviously won't happen and thank you for explaining me that.